# How to fix "Try the new cross-platform Powershell https://aka.ms/pscore6"?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

After installing Visual Studio Code, every time I compile a code, I receive a note like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: why bother, I think there is a setting in Powershell that will hide the startup message

Comment: Have you maybe tried doing what the message says and download the newer Powershell version?

Comment: The linked post shows how to pass parameters to the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) ) on startup. Use `-NoLogo` to suppress the unwanted message (including the first two lines with the copyright message).

Comment: @RemyLebeau this message always pops up in PS5, even if you have PS7 installed. It's just the default banner which comes with PS5 which MS never bothered to update.